# Android12 - StartActivity not working post Picture-in-Picture mode Expansion

Tags: android, start-activity, android-12, android-picture-in-picture

I am working on an App which uses Android's Picture-in-Picture Mode.

The MainActivity has a button which launches some other activity(simply fire intent to another Activity). The issue occurs when i enter the PIP Mode and expands the MainActivity, Now when i click the Button, The new Activity takes around 7-8 seconds to become visible. Also if the pattern is repeated, The intent of the activity is completely ignored and SampleActivity never launches.

Everything is working fine below Android-12. Happening on Pixel devices(as 12 is available only on pixels for now.)

Here are sample code snippets(Sample project code with same problem).

Manifest file:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:taskAffinity=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SampleActivity" />
```

**PIP Mode:**

```
enterPictureInPictureMode(
            PictureInPictureParams.Builder().setActions()
                .setAspectRatio(
                    Rational(
                        140,
                        190
                    )
                )
                .build()
        )
```

**Button Click Intent**

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnClickMe).setOnClickListener {
            (it as? Button)?.text = "Clicked"
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SampleActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Tried playing with Manifest flags/configs but no luck. Pls provide necessary suggestions.

Comment: Previously asked if you have created an official Android bug report but I found it, in case someone want's to star it. Here it is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207397151
Thanks for creating this bug report.